# How to dynamically load an assembly from custom directory including its dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution, resolve

I found the following code that loads a dll dynamically from a custom location:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
}

private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "libs", new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll");
    if (File.Exists(assemblyPath) == false) return null;
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    return assembly;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var zip = ZipFile.Read("test.zip");

    foreach (ZipEntry file in zip)
    {
        file.Extract(".", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

In some cases this solution works, but with the ZipDotNet dll I'm getting:

```
InnerException  {"File or assembly name \"Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c\" or one of its dependencies, was not found. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)":"Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c"}   System.Exception {System.IO.FileLoadException}
```

Since its passing `if (File.Exists(assemblyPath) == false) return null;` I' guessing its a problem with loading the depencies of Ionic.Zip.dll? How would I resolve them, too?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx ?

Comment: Try to compare it to the original sample from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Comment: Can't really believe it, but Dennis is right ... for some reason the Ionic.Zip.dll was locked and unlocking it fixed the issue ... thanks for that good hint :)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code of Iconic.Zip.dll [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96133#1639326), I see that the only references in the project are to System, System.Data, System.Security, and System.Xml, so I doubt the reason is that you are unable to load any of its references.

I think your assembly resolve method is a little too simple. It is assuming the assembly name is the same as the file name, which is not always the case. So what you can do is get the `AssemblyName` for each of the dlls in the target folder and store a mapping of names to files. Then when the resolver requests a name you look it up in your known names and load the assembly file. Here is a quick implementation of the idea.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> assemblyNameToFileMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetAssemblyNames();
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
}

private void GetAssemblyNames()
{
  string folderPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "libs");
  foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.dll"))
  {
     try
     {
         AssemblyName name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file);
         assemblyNameToFileMapping.Add(name.FullName, file);
     }
     catch { } // Just move on if we can't get the name.
  }
}

private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string file;
    if (assemblyNameToFileMapping.TryGetValue(args.Name, out file))
    {
       return Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
    }
    return null;
}
```